# create tensor in specific indexes without loops

Tags: python, loops, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor `t1` (with shape `(2*n, 2*n)`, and I need to create tensor `t2` (with shape `(2*n)`) with the values of `t1` at `[i,(i+n) mod 2n]` for each row `i`.

For example, given:

```
t1 = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   [9 ,10,11,12],
                   [13,14,15,16]])
```

Here `n=2`.

`t2` has to be `[3,8,9,14]`.

I have this code:

```
t2 = torch.tensor([t1[i,(i+n)%(2*n)] for i in range(2*n)])
```

but Im searching a way without loops.

Comment: Take a look at my alternative solution below, using `torch.roll` and `torch.masked_select`.

Answer (score 2):

You could create the list of indices beforehand *with a loop* then pick the values from `t1` with [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) without having to loop over them yourself:

```
>>> index = torch.tensor([[(i+n)%(2*n)] for i in range(2*n)])

>>> torch.gather(t1, 1, index).flatten()
tensor([ 3,  8,  9, 14])
```

Alternatively, you can use [`torch.roll`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.roll.html) to shift by `n` an `(2*n, 2*n)` identity matrix, multiply by `t1` to get a mask and apply that to `t1` with [`torch.masked_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.masked_select.html):

```
>>> mask = torch.eye(2*n).roll(n, 1).bool()
tensor([[False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False,  True],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False, False]])

>>> torch.masked_select(t1, mask)
tensor([ 3,  8,  9, 14])
```